# mapping URL arguments in Python Requests redirect

Tags: python, routes, url-routing, redirect

While using the [Routes](http://routes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library I want to [redirect](http://routes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uni_redirect_rest.html#redirect-routes) certain URLs. The documentation says it can be achieved like this:

```
map.redirect("/legacyapp/archives/{url:.*}", "/archives/{url}")
```

And I am indeed able to redirect to a URL this way. However I am unable to map/parse the URL arguments from the request to the redirect. My code looks like this:

```
app.mapper.redirect( "/repository/status_for_installed_repository{url:.*}", "/api/repositories/check_updates/{url}" )
```

and if the app is passed this:

```
curl -L 'FQDN/repository/status_for_installed_repository?owner=qqqqqq&changeset_revision=e5f6ced3e91f&name=asdsadsadas'
```

it redirects me to

```
GET /api/repositories/check_updates
```

but I cannot find a way how to obtain the values of `owner` `name` and `changeset_revision`.

I expect this to be a common use case as generally you do not want to lose arguments when redirecting?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing it as follows:

```
def _map_redirects( app ):
    """
    Add redirect to the Routes mapper and forward the received query string.
    Subsequently when the redirect is triggered in Routes middleware the request
    will not even reach the webapp.
    """
    def forward_qs(environ, result):
        qs_dict = urlparse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
        for qs in qs_dict:
            result[ qs ] = qs_dict[ qs ]
        return True

    app.mapper.redirect( "/repository/status_for_installed_repository", "/api/repositories/check_updates/", _redirect_code="301 Moved Permanently", conditions=dict( function=forward_qs ) )
    return app
```